# Positioning the colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I have a matplotlib plot with a colorbar attached. I want to position the colorbar so that it is horizontal, and underneath my plot.

I have almost done this via the following:

```
plt.colorbar(orientation="horizontal",fraction=0.07,anchor=(1.0,0.0))
```

But the colorbar is still overlapping with the plot slightly (and the labels of the x axis). I want to move the colorbar further down, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Edit**: Updated for `matplotlib` version >= 3.

Three great ways to do this have already been shared [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43425119/1812739).

The [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) advises to use `inset_locator`. This would work as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
im = ax.imshow(rng.random((11, 16)))
ax.set_xlabel("x label")

axins = inset_axes(ax,
                    width="100%",  
                    height="5%",
                    loc='lower center',
                    borderpad=-5
                   )
fig.colorbar(im, cax=axins, orientation="horizontal")
```

[image: code output]

Comment: please give a complete example which is runable.

Comment: I think rather than `ax1.plot(your_data)` you want `img = ax1.imshow(your_data)` then the last line is `cb = plt.colorbar(img, cax=cbaxes)`.

Comment: I love this answer because it works just really nice in my examples. EXCEPT when I add a caption for the colobar. Then I can't see that. Can you help?

Answer (score 123):

#### using padding `pad`

In order to move the colorbar relative to the subplot, one may use the `pad` argument to `fig.colorbar`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
im = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(11,16))
ax.set_xlabel("x label")

fig.colorbar(im, orientation="horizontal", pad=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### using an axes divider

One can use an instance of `make_axes_locatable` to divide the axes and create a new axes which is perfectly aligned to the image plot. Again, the `pad` argument would allow to set the space between the two axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
im = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(11,16))
ax.set_xlabel("x label")

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.new_vertical(size="5%", pad=0.7, pack_start=True)
fig.add_axes(cax)
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### using subplots

One can directly create two rows of subplots, one for the image and one for the colorbar. Then, setting the `height_ratios` as `gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":[1, 0.05]}` in the figure creation, makes one of the subplots much smaller in height than the other and this small subplot can host the colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

fig, (ax, cax) = plt.subplots(nrows=2,figsize=(4,4), 
                  gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":[1, 0.05]})
im = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(11,16))
ax.set_xlabel("x label")

fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use your second example to place the colorbar on top of the image? I tried setting `cax = divider.append_axes("top", size="5%", pad=.15)`, but then the tick marks overlaps the image. I've been trying to place it outwards following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939063/matplotlib-colorbar-ticks-on-left-opposite-side) without any success, as it was written using very unorthodox `matplotlib` objects that I'm unable to reproduce in your example.

Comment: The last solution (with subplot) makes the shrink parameter useless and without effect. Any idea why?

Comment: @T.Boutelier Yes, that's expected. `shrink` does not apply to externally created axes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! So how is it possible to control the size of the colorbar with this solution (subplot)?

Comment: By creating a 2x3 grid (instead of 2x1), let the image fill all 3 columns, but the colorbar only the middle one.

Comment: How do you let the image filling the 3 columns? Doing `ax[0,:].imshow() ` generates an error. Isn't it necessary to rely on `GridSpec` in that case?

Comment: Correct. You'd use a GridSpec.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is that an easy way to fully control the cbar such as moving it to the left or the right?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how would you apply gridspec to this example in the case of a color bar spanning multiple plots?

Answer (score 1):

This has gotten a lot easier with **matplotlib version 3.7**, where you now can simply use the `location='bottom'` keyword.

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html#matplotlib-pyplot-colorbar):

> ```
> location : None or {'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'}
>     The location, relative to the parent axes, where the colorbar axes
>     is created.  It also determines the *orientation* of the colorbar
>     (colorbars on the left and right are vertical, colorbars at the top
>     and bottom are horizontal).  If None, the location will come from the
>     *orientation* if it is set (vertical colorbars on the right, horizontal
>     ones at the bottom), or default to 'right' if *orientation* is unset.
> ```

Example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
im = ax.imshow(rng.random((11, 16)))
ax.set_xlabel("x label")
fig.colorbar(im, location='bottom')
```

[image]