# Can I place a vertical colorbar to the left of the plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

From the [matplotlib command summary for the colorbar method](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=colorbar#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar) I am aware that the keyword argument `orientation := 'horizontal' | 'vertical'` as a parameter places an *horizontal* bar *underneath* the plot or a *vertical* to the *right* of it respectively.

Yet, in my situation, I would rather place the colour bar at the opposite side of the default (without too much fiddling... if possible).

How could I code this? Am I missing some obvious feature?

Comment: One way of doing this is to manually create extra axes for the colorbar: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multi_image.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to make sure the colorbar is in its own axis. You can adapt from this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
axp = ax.imshow(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 100)))
# Adding the colorbar
cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])  # This is the position for the colorbar
cb = plt.colorbar(axp, cax = cbaxes)
plt.show()
```

which results in this:

[image: Matplotlib colorbar on the left side of plot]

Comment: Is it possible to make the numbers on the colorbar appear on the left side of it?

Comment: @samlaf Never tried it but apparently yes. Check the SO question [Matplotlib colorbar ticks on left/opposite side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939063/matplotlib-colorbar-ticks-on-left-opposite-side).

Answer (score 18):

I've found another method that avoids having to manually edit axes locations, and instead allows you to keep the colorbar linked to an existing plot axis by using the location keyword (method adapted initially from [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html)).

The location argument is meant to be used on colorbars which reference multiple axes in a list (and will throw an error if colorbar is given only one axis), but if you simply put your one axis in a list, it will allow you to use the argument. You can use the following code as an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
axp = ax.imshow(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 100)))
cb = plt.colorbar(axp,ax=[ax],location='left')
plt.show()
```

which yields this plot:

[image: plot]:

Comment: Wow, this is such a great hack. Thanks for adding the late answer! The approach of having to manually specify the axes location has been bugging me for years. You're a legend.

Comment: I got the error: `got an unexpected keyword argument 'location'`

Comment: @wander95 Me too if I only typed `ax=ax`. The problem is solved if `ax=[ax]` is used, as in the answer.