# How to find kwargs for colorbar matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking to add a label to a colorbar in Matplotlib, but more importantly, I'm trying to place the label where I want it.

I found set_label:

```
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label(units)
```

and I found a question where someone had rotated the text of the label:

```
cb.set_label(units, rotation = 270)
```

and I found a reference to the existence of set_label having kwargs:

[link for API](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html)

But WHERE can I find what kwargs are available to me? What I want to do is either locate the label above the colorbar or at the end of the colorbar.

Comment: Locating the label above the colorbar would just be a title `cb.set_title()`. I guess that kwargs are hidden within the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html)

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939063/matplotlib-colorbar-ticks-on-left-opposite-side.  Also note that the API for the `colorbar()` method can be found here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar (the link was in your link to the Colorbar API)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are probably two different questions.

#### 1) How to set a label on top of the colorbar?

Use `cb.ax.set_title("Mylabel")`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(25)
y = np.random.rand(25)
c = np.random.rand(25)

plt.scatter(x,y, c=c)
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.set_title("Mylabel")
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### 2) What keyword arguments are available for `colorbar.set_label`?

The label for a colorbar is essentially a label for an axis. Hence it accepts the same keyword arguments as [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel)

Those are `fontdict`, `labelpad` and any [`matplotlib.text.Text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) properties.

Hence you could also position the label using `rotation` and `position`

```
cb.set_label("Mylabel", rotation=0, position=(1,1))
```

[image]