# Match the size of an horizontal colorbar with the width of a square heatmap in Seaborn

Tags: heatmap, seaborn, colorbar

I want to produce a square heatmap in Seaborn with the colorbar below.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(5,4)

grid_kws = {"height_ratios": (.9, .05), "hspace": .5}
f, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(2, gridspec_kw=grid_kws)

ax = sns.heatmap(data,
                 ax=ax,
                 cbar_ax=cbar_ax,
                 annot=True,
                 square=True,
                 cbar_kws={ "orientation": "horizontal" })

plt.savefig("heatmap.png")
```

And here's the output:
[image: output]

How can I match the size of the colorbar with the size of the heatmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the second or third option from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43425119/4124317) to [positioning the colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310594/positioning-the-colorbar). Since it may not be obvious how to do that in the case of a seaborn plot.

#### using subplots

One can directly create two rows of subplots, one for the image and one for the colorbar as is done in the question, one would just need to make sure the figure size squeezes the plot horizontally, not vertically. In this case, try `figsize=(3,5)`.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(5,4)

grid_kws = {"height_ratios": (.9, .05), "hspace": .5}
fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(3,5), gridspec_kw=grid_kws)

ax = sns.heatmap(data,
                 ax=ax,
                 cbar_ax=cbar_ax,
                 annot=True,
                 square=True,
                 cbar_kws={ "orientation": "horizontal" })

#plt.savefig("heatmap.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### using axes divider

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

data = np.random.rand(5,4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cbar_ax = divider.new_vertical(size="5%", pad=0.5, pack_start=True)
fig.add_axes(cbar_ax)
ax = sns.heatmap(data,
                 ax=ax,
                 cbar_ax=cbar_ax,
                 annot=True,
                 square=True,
                 cbar_kws={ "orientation": "horizontal" })


#plt.savefig("heatmap.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the second solution worked perfectly. The first one caused problems of over-cropping when adding a label on the y axis on the left.