# Reduce horizontal colorbar padding

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to generate a plot with several axis, each one with their own colorbar (code below). If I use the default colorbar plotting I get too much horizontal spacing between the plot and the colorbar:

[image]

If I try to use the `make_axes_locatable()` method I get this horrible result:

[image]

What is going on and how can I fix this?

---

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# Random data to plot
data = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (2, 100))
z = np.random.uniform(0., 10., 100)

# Define figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(12, 12)

for i in range(2):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[2 * i:2 + (2 * i), 0:8])

    SC = plt.scatter(*data, c=z)

    # Colorbar 1
    cbar = plt.colorbar()

    # Colorbar 2
    # the_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    # color_axis = the_divider.append_axes("right", size="1%", pad=0.)
    # cbar = plt.colorbar(SC, cax=color_axis)

    cbar.set_label("test", fontsize=15, labelpad=10)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: the answer below was faster than me :) if you need it a reference is here also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310594/positioning-the-colorbar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `pad` argument of `colorbar` to set the padding between the axes and the colorbar. `pad` is given in units of the fraction of the original axes' size to use as space. Here e.g. `pad=0.01` might make sense.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Random data to plot
data = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (2, 100))
z = np.random.uniform(0., 10., 100)

# Define figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(30, 30))

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    sc = ax.scatter(*data, c=z)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax, pad=0.01)
    cbar.set_label("test", fontsize=15, labelpad=10)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: So much easier than I thought. Thank you!