# How to resize the width of the plot with a colorbar in multiplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with a color bar in multiplot. 
The two plots are not aligned when I add the color bar.
If I remove the color bar, the plots are aligned nicely.

How to resize the plots in multiplot?
I just want to resize the width either lower or upper plot in oder to align the plots.
Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.subplots(2,figsize=(5, 8))
gs  = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[ 3,2],hspace=0.0)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])

xx   = np.linspace(0,5,50)
yy   = np.linspace(0,5,50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
T = X**2 

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=10)
pcm=ax1.pcolormesh(X,Y,T, norm =norm)
plt.colorbar(pcm, orientation="vertical", ax =ax1)

ax2.plot(xx, xx**2)
```

And, here is the result.

[image: the result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Positioning the Color Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13311914/4046274) answer we can add a new axis **without grid spec**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)  #Create 2x1 grid and declare ax1 as first plot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)  #Create 2x1 grid and declare ax2 as second plot

xx   = np.linspace(0,5,50)
yy   = np.linspace(0,5,50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
T = X**2 

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=10)
pcm=ax1.pcolormesh(X,Y,T, norm =norm)

cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.53, 0.03, 0.35]) #Add position (left, bottom, width, height)
cb = plt.colorbar(pcm, cax = cbaxes) 
ax2.plot(xx, xx**2)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try a horizontal bar orientation too.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.subplots(2,figsize=(5, 8))
gs  = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[ 3,2],hspace=0.0)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])

xx   = np.linspace(0,5,50)
yy   = np.linspace(0,5,50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
T = X**2 

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=10)
pcm=ax1.pcolormesh(X,Y,T, norm =norm)
plt.colorbar(pcm, orientation="horizontal", ax =ax1, pad=0.1)

ax2.plot(xx, xx**2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I got a solution. But, I just add my own axis and put the color bar on that the defined axis.
I am still wondering how to make this kind of plot easily.

```
fig  = plt.figure(2,figsize=(5, 8))
gs   = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[ 3,2],hspace=0.0)

axes = fig.add_axes([0.25,0.425,0.78,0.455])

ax1  = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2  = plt.subplot(gs[1])

xx   = np.linspace(0,5,50)
yy   = np.linspace(0,5,50)
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

TY = XX**2 
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=10)
pcm =ax1.pcolormesh(XX,YY,TY, norm =norm)

plt.colorbar(pcm, orientation="vertical", ax =axes);

ax2.plot(xx, xx**2);
```

Here is a better plot.

[image]